# Query failed with error code 6 and error message 'HostUnreachable' on server

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding

I have a mongo sharded cluster.

I have been facing intermittent issues in my application(while fetching data from mongo) seeing these logs,

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error
>   code 6 and error message 'HostUnreachable' on server
>   10.95.107.220:27017
>           at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:722)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:711)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:470)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:414)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
>           at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:822)
>           at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:809)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:870)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:141)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCursor.one(DBCursor.java:679)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:829)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:792)
>           at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:739)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2169)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2153)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1905)

The issue is intermittent, but still is occurring quite often now.

I have looked, I am able to connect all of the mongo boxes manually and each mongo can telnet to other mongo instances on port 27017.

Any reasoning behind this? Ad how can I fix it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS: Mongo java driver is 3.6 and ulimit is also set greater than 32000, as suggested [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29006)

Comment: Intermittent issue with a `HostUnreachable` message typically means the network connection you're using is not stable. It may cut off multiple times in a day, hence the unpredictable nature of the issue. Generally, if it can work once, it should work again, so this kind of issue is typically not under the control of the database.

Comment: I am not in denial of any network issues (there maybe).
By intermittent, I mean not every request fails, but still issue is quite often. But I need to get into root of it and fix it, since its impacting quite a lot now.